# detect mouse click in parent form, but outside child form

Tags: c#, winforms

i am trying to implement a UI whereby the parent form loads a child form through showDialog(). the child form would be closed whenever i click anywhere outside the child form, but inside the parent form. clicking anywhere outside the parent form would only cause a normal "alt-tab" action. how do i do this?

Comment: This pretty basically cannot work, the parent form is disabled while the dialog is displayed.  It can't receive any input events, Windows will just beep you.  You'll have to give up on the idea of using ShowDialog().  It is otherwise simple with Show() and the form's Deactivate event.

Comment: hmmm everything is working with the show() and deactivate event, except that for the normal alt tab event the form will deactivate too. how do i set it such that it will only disappear when the "focus" is changed to the parent form?

Comment: Then use that form's Activate event instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any controls in the form (if you're viewing a picture for example). Then you can just capture the mouse:

```
    protected override void OnLoad( EventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnLoad( e );
        this.Capture = true;
    }
```

And after that, you just check in OnMouseDown if the click is outside your form.

Othewise, this code *could* be used:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if ( m.Msg==0x86 && (int)m.WParam==0 )
            if ( this.DialogResult==DialogResult.None )
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        base.WndProc (ref m);
    }
```

It worked great in Windows XP, but in Windows 7 it sounds a beep too, and I haven't investigated why.

Comment: +1 - if anyone does know the beep fix for Win7 please share it here?

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same behavior.

When my application starts, an advertising form is shown and has to be closed whenever the user click on the main form.

Based on the [WM_SETCURSOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, here my solution (to put in the main form) :

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
        var vanishingDialog = ActiveForm as IVanishingDialog;

        //0x0201FFFE is for : 0201 (left button down) and FFFE (HTERROR).
        if ((m.Msg == 0x20) && (m.LParam.ToInt32() == 0x0201FFFE) && (vanishingDialog != null))
        {
            vanishingDialog.Vanish();
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
}
```

And my Advertising dialog (or whatever you want to see disappear on a click to the main form) will implement this interface :

```
public interface IVanishingDialog
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Closes the dialog box.
    /// </summary>
    void Vanish();
}
```

Work like a charm on seven (no beep).

I just need to improve it in one way :
When the user click on a button in the main form, the advertising form close but the button is not pressed.
I have to transform and send a new message.

Comment: By the way, I should stop to use singleton pattern.